# Unable to create dictionary in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, xcode6

I am not able to create dictionary in objective c. I am getting warning as

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending nsinteger to parameter

Below is my code.

```
 NSString *tmpSessionID = [[[AppSettings sharedAppSettings] getUserSession] objectForKey:@"UserSessionId"];
  int tmpRepoId = [[[[AppSettings sharedAppSettings] getUserRepository] objectForKey:@"RepositoryId" ]intValue];
  int tmpUserID = [[[[AppSettings sharedAppSettings] getUserSession] objectForKey:@"UserId"]intValue];
  NSDictionary * fmDic = [[AppSettings sharedAppSettings] getFolderModel];
  int containerId = containerId = [[fmDic objectForKey:@"ContainerId"]intValue];
  int docTypeId = selectedDcoumentType.docTypeId;
  NSDictionary *metaData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       selectFileIndices.columnId, @"ColumnId",
                       indexValue, @"Value",
                       nil];
  NSMutableArray *metaArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [metaArray addObject:metaData];
  NSDictionary *metaDataFiellds = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   metaArray, @"metaDataFields",
                                   nil];

  NSDictionary *allImportDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            containerId, @"containerId",
                            docTypeId, @"docTypeId",selectFileIndices.transText, @"fileExt",metaDataFiellds, @"metaDataFields",tmpRepoId, @"repositoryId",1, @"pagesCount",
                                 tmpSessionID, @"sessionId", @"1487918350642.jpg", @"title",guid, @"tmpFileName",tmpUserID, @"userId",
                            nil];
  NSLog(@"dictionary is %@",allImportDict);
```

I want to create a json like below:

```
{
  "containerId": 2,
  "docTypeId": 1,
  "fileExt": ".jpg",
  "metaDataFields": [
    {
      "ColumnId": 1,
      "Value": "23"
    }
  ],
  "pagesCount": 1,
  "repositoryId": 1,
  "sessionId": "1587c3c9-f261-4749-ace4-c134d031ec38",
  "title": "1487918350642.jpg",
  "tmpFileName": "5f8a0340-bd65-476c-b377-67fa19121203",
  "userId": 5
}
```

Comment: which line you got the error

Comment: NSDictionary cannot store scalar values (like BOOL, NSInteger, etc.), it can store only objects. You must wrap your scalar values into NSNumber to store them:  [NSNumber numberWithInteger containerId]

Comment: You know nobody writes Objective-C like this nowadays. Have you heard about dictionary literals or subscript access ?

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary accepts objects only, no basic types. You'll need to wrap your int inside an NSNumber

`[NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpRepoId]`

or, in modern Obj-C:

`@(tmpRepoId)`

and add this to the dictionary.

Generally, I'd like to recommend to use modern Obj-C for better readability, e.g.:

```
int containerId fmDic[@"ContainerId"].intValue;
NSDictionary *metaDataFiellds = @{ @"metaDataFields" : metaArray };
```

Also consider using NSInteger instead of int.